# Exclude first record associated with each parent record in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, offset

There are 2 tables, `users` and `job_experiences`.

I want to return a list of all `job_experiences` except the first associated with each user.

**users**

```
id 
---
1
2
3
```

**job_experiences**

```
id | start_date | user_id
--------------------------
1  | 201001     | 1
2  | 201201     | 1
3  | 201506     | 1
4  | 200901     | 2
5  | 201005     | 2
```

**Desired result**

```
id | start_date | user_id
--------------------------
2  | 201201     | 1
3  | 201506     | 1
5  | 201005     | 2
```

**Current query**

```
select 
   * 
from job_experiences
order by start_date asc
offset 1
```

But this doesn't work as it would need to apply the offset to each user individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a lateral join:

```
select je.*
from users u cross join lateral
     (select je.*
      from job_experiences je
      where u.id = je.user_id
      order by id
      offset 1  -- all except the first
     ) je;
```

For performance, an index on `job_experiences(user_id, id)` is recommended.

Comment: This is really slow over a large number of records. Any thoughts to speed it up?

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number()` window function

```
with cte as
(
 select e.*,
 row_number()over(partition by user_id order by start_date desc) rn,
 count(*) over(partition by user_id) cnt
 from users u join job_experiences e on u.id=e.user_id
)
, cte2 as
(
 select * from cte 
) select * from cte2 t1
where rn<=(select max(cnt)-1 from cte2 t2 where t1.user_id=t2.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an intermediate CTE to get the first (`MIN`) jobs for each user, and then use that to determine which records to exclude:

```
WITH user_first_je("user_id", "job_id") AS
(
    SELECT "user_id", MIN("id")
    FROM job_experiences
    GROUP BY "user_id"
)
SELECT job_experiences.* 
FROM job_experiences
    LEFT JOIN user_first_je ON
        user_first_je.job_id = job_experiences.id
WHERE user_first_je.job_id IS NULL;
```